# How to get relative path from UriInfo

Tags: java, path, jax-rs

I'm working with JAX-RS in Java.
I need to get from the UriInfo the relative path of the URI, i.e. the URI without the scheme and authority parts but with path and query parameters.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html if you call

```
 getPath()
```

You will "Get the path of the current request relative to the base URI as a string."

Comment: Thanks but this solution will not give me the query params

Comment: Do not know what application server you are using, You can try to inject this:
@Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest; and then use servletRequest to fetch data

Answer (score 1):

I needed the exact same thing although few years later. Nevertheless here's how.

```
URI requestURI = this.uriInfo.getRequestUri();
URI baseUri = this.uriInfo.getBaseUri();
URI uri = baseUri.relativize(requestURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sourceUrl = "http://www.example.com/mysite/whatever/somefolder/bar/unsecure!+?#whätyöühäv€it/site.html"; // your current site
    String targetUrl = "http://www.example.com/mysite/whatever/otherfolder/other.html"; // the link target
    String expectedTarget = "../../../otherfolder/other.html";
    String[] sourceElements = sourceUrl.split("/");
    String[] targetElements = targetUrl.split("/"); // keep in mind that the arrays are of different length!
    StringBuilder uniquePart = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder relativePart = new StringBuilder();
    boolean stillSame = true;
    for(int ii = 0; ii < sourceElements.length || ii < targetElements.length; ii++) {
        if(ii < targetElements.length && ii < sourceElements.length && 
                stillSame && sourceElements[ii].equals(targetElements[ii]) && stillSame) continue;
        stillSame = false;
        if(targetElements.length > ii)
          uniquePart.append("/").append(targetElements[ii]);
        if(sourceElements.length > ii +1)
            relativePart.append("../");
    }

    String result = relativePart.toString().substring(0, relativePart.length() -1) + uniquePart.toString();
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
String uri = "http://google.com/path?q1=va";
    int index = -1;
    if ((index = uri.indexOf("://")) > 0) {
        uri = uri.substring(index + 3);
    }
    index = uri.indexOf('/');
    uri = uri.substring(index);
    System.out.println(uri);
```

or like this:

```
    URI uri  = new URI("http://google.com/path?q1=va");
    System.out.println(uri.getPath()+"?"+uri.getQuery());
```